# How can I display the default file app on Android's share sheet?

Tags: android, android-intent, share

I am developing a note taking app, and I am developing a feature that exports it as a PDF document.

Through the following guide, we implemented the function to send to another app as action.send.
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters

However, Android's default 'Files' app is not displayed on the android share sheet.
I would like to implement the logic to save to the device via Android's native Files app.

```
val intent = Intent()
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION)

intent.action = Intent.ACTION_SEND
intent.type = "*/*"

val uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, context.packageName + ".sharefileprovider", sharedFile)
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri)
val intentChooser = Intent.createChooser(intent, "ShareTest")
context.startActivity(intentChooser)
```

[I want the Files app to be displayed on the Share sheet like this image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OXOAb.png)

Is there any solution for this?

Comment: Files by Google is displayed if you share in the normal way.

Comment: `I would like to implement the logic to save to the device via Android's native Files app.` Why? If you share a file that file is already on the device. Why twice?

Comment: I have added my code. Even with all types displayed, the default Files app is not displayed.
To be precise, the data you store is your own data, not PDF, and it is converted to PDF at the time of sharing.

Comment: `To be precise, the data you store is your own data, not PDF, ` Yes its your data. And it is already a .pdf file. And you are trying to share that pdf file and not some data. Then what would be `sharedFile`?

Comment: What kind of device does not display Files by Google to share with a friend. Not to save to storage.